# Concatenate 2 dataframes with uneven lengths and no index

Tags: python, pandas

How do you concatenate 2 dataframes with uneven lengths and no index

```
y=[152,176,160,192,220,272,256,280,300,280,312,328]
df= pd.DataFrame({'a':y})

z=[np.nan, np.nan,176.,195.84, 217.8816, 241.242,   272.1758,
  292.7523,  313.2483,  332.8503,  341.3608,  352.8076,  363.6765,  360.4414,
  379.522]

df2=pd.DataFrame({'b':z})
```

I want the output as

```
           b   a
0        NaN   152
1        NaN   176
2   176.0000   160
3   195.8400   192
4   217.8816   220
5   241.2420   272
6   272.1758   256
7   292.7523   280
8   313.2483   300
9   332.8503   280
10  341.3608   312
11  352.8076   328
12  363.6765
13  360.4414
14  379.5220

[15 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every pandas DataFrame has an index, even if you don't specify it explicitely. In that case the index is composed of integers from 0 to n:

```
>>> df.index
Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], dtype=int64)
```

So if the DataFrames are in the right order, you can simply use `concat` like so:

```
pd.concat([df2, df], axis=1)
```

which returns:

```
           b    a
0        NaN  152
1        NaN  176
2   176.0000  160
3   195.8400  192
4   217.8816  220
5   241.2420  272
6   272.1758  256
7   292.7523  280
8   313.2483  300
9   332.8503  280
10  341.3608  312
11  352.8076  328
12  363.6765  NaN
13  360.4414  NaN
14  379.5220  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any advantage to making separate DataFrames first. I haven't been able to think of a way to do this in one line, but you can do it in two:

```
In [64]: df = DataFrame([y, z]).T

In [65]: df.columns = ['a', 'b']

In [66]: df
Out[66]:
      a         b
0   152       NaN
1   176       NaN
2   160  176.0000
3   192  195.8400
4   220  217.8816
5   272  241.2420
6   256  272.1758
7   280  292.7523
8   300  313.2483
9   280  332.8503
10  312  341.3608
11  328  352.8076
12  NaN  363.6765
13  NaN  360.4414
14  NaN  379.5220

[15 rows x 2 columns]
```